# Cardslib : use the demo project

Tags: android, cardslib

I use the Cardlib library in my project.
There is an other project in the github repository which named "demo".

I'm interested in using the StickyCardListView of the project "demo". But being a novice android developer as I am, I have no idea how I would proceed. How do I include those demo object in my personal project so I can use them.

I'm using Android Studio 2.0.

Thank you.

Comment: you should be implement this https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders with cardview.. because cardview is a layout. you should be easy put into layout...

Comment: https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/OTHERLIBRARIES.md#using-card-with-stickylistheaders

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I'v just duplicated 3 files of the demo project and that's works fine now.